# Zombie book set in Texas featuring two men and a dog who find a boat named "Bahama Mama"

Tags: story-identification, zombie-apocalypse

It's a zombie book set in Texas featuring two men and a dog with a name. They are on a pier and find a boat named "Bahama Mama". They save a family of 3, where the wife is a nurse. They also find a woman in a car named Tara. They find an underground military base and run into some Marines. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 15):

[Day by Day Armageddon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74821.Day_by_Day_Armageddon) by J. L. Bourne.

The book is written in the form of a journal. The entry with the boat is:

> February 21st, 0800 hrs
> ...
> The back end had drifted, facing the admin office door when I walked out. The boat's name was painted on the rear with a "half circle" type banner. It was the "Bahamas Mama." I jumped on to the stern and walked over to the wheel and inserted the key. John was still sitting on the dock, eyes trained toward the strips of hotels and the street. I slid the throttle to the start position, and turned the key. On the second attempt it started with no problems and I let it run for about five minutes.

The family that the protagonist rescues is *William*, his wife *Jan* and daughter *Laura*. As you say, Jan is a nurse. The family are besieged by the zombies in a derelict house. The protagonist lures the zombies away by opening fire on them and then driving away. With the zombies gone he drives back and rescues the family.

> I keyed the microphone and told William to get his family ready to get out onto the roof as near to the ledge as possible. I was going very slowly, so that they would give chase and stay with me. William told me over the CB that they were all following me and that the plan was working. The only ones left behind, were the ones I was lucky enough to put down with a freak headshot when I opened fire.
>
> Rounding the block, I waited until they were almost upon me until I hit the fucking gas and made for the Grisham house. I could see William, his wife, and a little girl on the roof. I drove the car up to the side of the house to lessen the distance they would have to jump. I got out and covered them as William jumped first and held his arms out for the others.

The entry mentioning *Tara* is:

> XIV - Ides of March
> March 15th, 1822 hrs
> Jan also tended to the new arrival, Tara. Tara had been trapped in that car for four days. She was on the verge of dying from dehydration when William and I showed up. She was feeling better.

The dog is an Italian Greyhound called *Annabelle* owned by one of the two men, *John*.